# Sending FormData object with multidimensional array to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html

The requirements for one of my controllers changed, it needed to be able to accept a file in addition to it's previous input types: string, string[] and string[][].

Before the file upload requirement it was just making an AJAX call with the 'application/json' contentType. I spotted that I can implement the file and string posting in a single AJAX call by creating a FormData object, append both the text and the file and have the controller accept HttpPostedFileBase.

Posting the file and string worked fine, the problem I encountered was handling javascript arrays. The previous version could quite easily handle it with JSON.stringify, but following the update that needed to change.

I eventually got it to work but I feel I'm missing a better way to handle populating arrays in the FormData object. Here's how it's currently implemented (fields renamed and content cleaned up for readability):

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestAR(string t1, string t2, string[][] t3,
string[] t4, HttpPostedFileBase t5)
{
}
```

Javascript

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('t1', $('#t1').val());
formData.append('t2', $('#t2').val());
$.each(t3, function (key1, value1) {
    $.each(value1, function (key2, value2) {
        formData.append('t3[' + key1 + '][' + key2 + ']', value2);
    });
});
$.each(t4, function (key1, value1) {
    formData.append('t4[' + key1 + ']', value1);
});
formData.append('t5', file);

var farr = [];
var valForm = $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("TestAR", "TC", null)',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
})
.done(function (result) {
    // ...
})
.fail(function (event, xhr, status, exc) {
    // ...
});
farr.push(valForm);
```

I feel like the array and the multidimensional array can be handled in a cleaner fashion in the FormData object but I can't figure out how I can do that. Is it possible to clean it up any more?